# Override the default action of save button in edit form

Tags: symfony-1.4

In edit form if we click save button it will take executeUpdate action of action.class.php file. But i want to call a customize executeUpdateSometing action function instead of executeUpdate action when user press the save button of the edit form. How can implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this, but both rely in some changes to the routing.

1. Change Form Action

In the tag `<form>` there is action attribute `<form action="">` which you can change to input a different route that points to your customised action for example:

```
 <form id="my_form" method="POST" action="<?php echo url_for('@route_to_custom_update')?>">
   //form fields go here
 </form>
```

When the user clicks on the submit button this will then submit the form via the custom route which points to the customer update action.

1. Use jQuery

Create a jQuery (or JS) function that listens for the form submission action and then submits form via the custom route.

You can change the routing in the `routing.yml` file either by updating the existing route

```
update_form:
  url: /update/url
  param: { module: your_module, action: updatesomething}
```

or by adding a new route & using that in the form action or jQuery Ajax call

```
something_update_form:
  url: /something/update/url
  param: { module: your_module, action: updatesomething}
```

Note: that if you add another route the URL will need to be different from the existing update url.

The [Symfony 1.4 documentation](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc) has more details on form submission & routing